# Ext JS Translation using PHP (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, extjs, extjs4, translation

**Translation Tip 1**:

I had a problem where I needed to make my application translatable for clients in other countries. All my custom strings in the application weren't covered by Ext JS's locale files so I had to come up with my own way of translating these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application, I use mo/po files to handle the translations on the server side.  Since I wanted to keep all my language strings in one central place (my .po file), I used a "Language.js" file rather than "English.js" and "French.js".  The content of the file looks something like this:

```
window.applanguage = {
    /*General form elements*/
    login : <?=$this->translate("Login")?>,
    OK: <?=$this->translate("OK")?>,
    changepassword: <?=$this->translate("Change password")?>,
    currentpassword: <?=$this->translate("Current password")?>,
    sam: <?=$this->translate("System Access Manager")?>,
    userid: <?=$this->translate("User ID")?>,
    adminid: <?=$this->translate("Admin ID")?>,
    email: <?=$this->translate("Email")?>,
    password: <?=$this->translate("Password")?>,
    newpassword: <?=$this->translate("New password")?>,
    confirmpassword: <?=$this->translate("Confirm password")?>,
    confirm: <?=$this->translate("Confirm")?>,
    confirmation: <?=$this->translate("Confirmation")?>,
    wentwrong: <?=$this->translate("Something went wrong")?>,
    username: <?=$this->translate("Username")?>,
    passvalidity: <?=$this->translate("Password Validity (days)")?>,
    product: <?=$this->translate("Product")?>,
    accesslevel: <?=$this->translate("Access Level")?>,
    timeoutmins: <?=$this->translate("Timeout (mins)")?>,
    cancel: <?=$this->translate("Cancel")?>,
    save: <?=$this->translate("Save")?>,
    reset: <?=$this->translate("Reset")?>,
    passwordutility: <?=$this->translate("Change password utility")?>,
    expireform: <?=$this->translate("Session expired, please log in to continue.")?>,
    adduser: <?=$this->translate("Add user")?>,
    edituser: <?=$this->translate("Edit user")?>,
    removeuser: <?=$this->translate("Remove user")?>,
    resetuser: <?=$this->translate("Reset user")?>,
    add: <?=$this->translate("Add")?>
};
```

This way, I keep all my translations at the same place and poedit can process the file to suggest the strings that need to be translated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a gettext javascript plugin for the frontend, such as Jed. http://slexaxton.github.io/Jed/. That would mean you can keep using gettext dictionaries for your entire app.

I ended up creating a `core.po` dictionary, which contains all the backend strings, and a `frontend.po` dictionary which is dedicated to the frontend.

You can generate an output that is suitable for jed plugin by using a simple conteoller. I open sourced some sections of the work I did while implementing it. see https://github.com/aporat/zend-translate-skelton/blob/master/library/TranslateGettext/BackendProxyController.php

The controller generates a Jed gettext dictionary, and this javascript is included in the layout.phtml

```
<script src="/language?language=en"></script>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

  class TranslateGettext_BackendProxyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
  {

    /**
     * See http://slexaxton.github.com/Jed/
     * This is a json proxy for the frontend i18n
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $localeCode = $this->_getParam('locale');
        $locale = new Zend_Locale($localeCode);

        $translate = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');

        if ($translate->isAvailable($locale->getLanguage())) {
            $entries = Gettext\Extractors\Po::extract(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../languages/' . $locale->getLanguage() . '/LC_MESSAGES/frontend.po');
        } else {
            $entries = Gettext\Extractors\Po::extract(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../languages/en/LC_MESSAGES/frontend.po');
        }

        echo 'var i18n = new Jed({locale_data : ';
        echo Gettext\Generators\Jed::generate($entries, true);
        echo '});';

        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey this seems pretty cool, thanks for the tip, looks like what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create an "English.js" file in a folder called "resources" (though you can call it "locale" or whatever you want). In this file I created an object containing all my custom strings that would need to be translated which looked a little something like below:

```
window.applanguage = {
    /*General form elements*/
    login : "Login",
    OK: "OK",
    changepassword: "Change password",
    currentpassword: "Current password",
    sam: "System Access Manager",
    userid: "User ID",
    adminid: "Admin ID",
    email: "Email",
    password: "Password",
    newpassword: "New password",
    confirmpassword: "Confirm password",
    confirm: "Confirm",
    confirmation: "Confirmation",
    wentwrong: "Something went wrong",
    username: "Username",
    passvalidity: "Password Validity (days)",
    product: "Product",
    accesslevel: "Access Level",
    timeoutmins: "Timeout (mins)",
    cancel: "Cancel",
    save: "Save",
    reset: "Reset",
    passwordutility: "Change password utility",
    expireform: "Session expired, please log in to continue.",
    adduser: "Add user",
    edituser: "Edit user",
    removeuser: "Remove user",
    resetuser: "Reset user",
    add: "Add"
};
```

Wherever I needed my custom string translated I just replaced it with `window.applanguage.string_to_translate`. I.E:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    closable: false,
    title: window.applanguage.info,
    msg: window.applanguage.selectuserfirst,
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
    icon: Ext.Msg.INFO
});
```

Now if you wanted your application in French (although tedious to do) you can copy the "English.js" file and name is "French,js" and change all the string to french.

**NB**: Don't forget to include your language file in the `<header>` of your web file. You can dynamically change this by having a global in PHP (I set mine in the ZF application.ini file) with the language to you want to display and then in your header you can then have the line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/resources/<?php echo $languageFile; ?>.js"></script>`

**Translation Tip 2**:

If you needed to translate all the Ext JS components to language other than English you can include the EXT JS locale file in your `header`. For example if you want French:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-4.2.0/locale/ext-lang-fr.js"></script>`

Using the dynamic PHP option it would look something like this (This is for ZF but you could just use a global variable in your app):

```
// get params from application.ini
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('../application/configs/application.ini', 'development');
$langFile = $config->tranlation->language->file;
$extLang = null;
switch($langFile){
    case 'English':
        $extLang= "ext-lang-en_GB";
        break;
    case 'French':
        $extLang= "ext-lang-fr";
        break;
    case 'Spanish':
        $extLang= "ext-lang-es";
        break;
    case 'German':
        $extLang= "ext-lang-de";
        break;
    case 'Chinese (Simplified)':
        $extLang= "ext-lang-zh_CN";
        break;
    case 'Chinese (Traditional)':
        $extLang= "ext-lang-zh_TW";
        break;
}
```

and then in your `<header>` place this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-4.2.0/locale/<?php echo $extLang; ?>.js"></script>`